# How to preg_split using PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE

Tags: php, regex

```
$str = "blabla and, some more blah";
$delimiters = " ,¶.\n";
$char_buff = preg_split("/(,) /", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($char_buff);
```

I get:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => blabla and 
  [1] => , 
  [2] => some more blah 
)
```

I was able to figure out how to use the parenthesis to get the comma to show up in its own array element -- but how can I do this with multiple different delimiters (for example, those in the $delimiters variable)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) by wrapping the delimiters with `[` and `]`.

```
<?php
$str = "blabla and, some more blah. Blah.\nSecond line.";
$delimiters = " ,¶.\n";
$char_buff = preg_split('/([' . $delimiters . '])/', $str, -1,
             PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($char_buff);
```

You also need to use `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` so that in places where you get two matches in a row, for instance a comma followed by a space, you don't get an empty match.

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => blabla
    [1] =>  
    [2] => and
    [3] => ,
    [4] =>  
    [5] => some
    [6] =>  
    [7] => more
    [8] =>  
    [9] => blah
    [10] => .
    [11] =>  
    [12] => Blah
    [13] => .
    [14] => 

    [15] => Second
    [16] =>  
    [17] => line
    [18] => .
)
```

Depending on what you are doing, using [strtok](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) may be a more appropriate way of doing it though.

Comment: Great - that works.  Is there a good reference for how to learn regex related to matching?  I've learned and then forgotten (basic) regex several times because I don't use it enough.  I'd like to figure out how I can capture some delimiters but not others.

Comment: @key2starz You do a non-capturing group by starting the group with `(?:`.  I've always found [Regular-expression.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) a handy reference.  Their page on [groups and backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) has more info on the subject.

Comment: This answer is misinforming researchers.  The `m` pattern modifier is completely useless here.  There are no anchors involved (`^` and `$`) so `m` offer no benefit.

Comment: @mickmackusa You're right, I'm not sure what I was thinking, I probably just saw that `\n` was one of delimiters and assumed you would need `m`. I'm also not sure why I didn't mention the character class around the delimiters. I've updated the answer, thanks.

Comment: In some cases (when passing characters with special meanings to regex), you should use `preg_quote()` when writing variables into an expression (not the case in this example).

Answer (score 2):

Use something like:

```
'/([,.])/'
```

That is put each delimiter in that square bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Each delimiter expression needs to be inside its own group.

```
print_r(preg_split('/2\d4/'      , '12345', null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE)); 
Array ( [0] => 1                            [1] => 5 )

print_r(preg_split('/(2)(\d)(4)/', '12345', null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE)); 
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 )
```